# How to Use SVG with React and ReasonML?

Tags: reactjs, reason, rescript

With `create-react-app` and JavaScript/TypeScript, I understand I'm able to "import" an SVG as noted below. How may I do so with ReasonML?

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
      <Logo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create React App uses webpack to transform SVG files into React components. If you’re using Reason with CRA, then all you need to do is provide a binding to the generated component. However, CRA will only transform the SVG into a component if the import statement is written exactly a certain way, which isn't how BuckleScript outputs import statements. ([There's a GitHub issue about it here.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6258)) You have to import it with raw JavaScript and then bind to the imported value:

```
%bs.raw
{|import {ReactComponent as _Logo} from "./logo.svg"|};

module Logo = {
  [@react.component] [@bs.val] external make: unit => React.element = "_Logo";
};

/* And we can use it like a regular component: */
[@react.component]
let make = () =>
  <div>
    <Logo />
  </div>;
```

[According to the CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs):

> The imported SVG React Component accepts a `title` prop along with other props that a `svg` element accepts.

For any of the other props you want to use, you'll have to add them to your `external` binding.

If you're **not** using CRA, then you'll need to configure your bundler to do the same transformation. I'm not familiar with the internals of CRA, but [this seems to be the relevant code from its webpack configuration.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4d26208d401161bffce482f3ad161412457850ab/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L416)

Answer (score 2):

We can use [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) to handle the webpack loading and then import the module as we normally would.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  //...
};
```

```
module Logo = {
  @bs.module(`../../../../src/img/logo.svg`) @react.component
  external make: {.} => React.element = "default"
}

... 

<Logo /> // works
```

source: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of another solution that doesn't involve webpack.
It's a tool that can transform your svg files directly into .re files: https://github.com/MoOx/react-from-svg
This can create files for react (dom) or react-native(-web) (=> files generated use react-native-svg).
Feel free to try it :)

For example you can do (when the tool is installed from npm)

```
$ react-from-svg src/SVGs src/SVGs/components --with-native-for-reason --remove-fill
```

This will turns the files from `svg/SVGs` into React components into `src/SVGs/components` compatible for React Native with the Reason syntax.
The last option remove all svg fill props so you can use them as icons.

Note that the generated components accept `width`, `height` & `fill` props so you can adjust them when used.

Last bonus: since webpack is not involved, you can use this transformation only when you update your SVGs files & use this code directly with a Node runtime (JSX from Reason gets removed when converted to JS so the code can be consumed directly via Node without any transformation - which can be handy for tiny static sites/pages).